# What Dread Powers do the Demons have?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, hunter-the-vigil

Ch 5, p119  of Mortal Remains is about Demons, however there is no  **Dread Powers** Section like there are in the the other chapters. I'm going to speculate that this might be because of there being multiple kinds of Demons listed. Could anyone provide a synopsis of which Dread Powers applies to which kinds of demons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dread powers and demons

Quoting from nWoD : Inferno

> **Dread Powers of the Diabolique**
>
> The Children of the Seventh Generation do not have pre-established
>   abilities shared between members. Each of its members is unique, born
>   of a singular bloodline stirred from the depths of Hell. Each of the
>   antagonists below has his own Infernal aspects he can manifest, and
>   you’re free to borrow these—or any of the hellish Numina or Vestments
>   in this—to serve the antagonists you create.

But you can look into Page 283 of the Hunter book to get your stats for Demons, and find these examples:

> ￼BEDSHAKER | LESSER DEMON
>
> Dread Powers: Hypnotism •••
>
> ￼MISTER WHITE | GREATER DEMON
>
> Dread Powers: Balefire •, Confuse •••, Hypnotism ••
>
> THE NEIGHBORHOOD | ELDER DEMON
>
> Dread Powers: Animal Control Numen (••), Damnation •••••, Fury •, Telekinesis Numen (••)
>
> DJ CENTI | GREATER DEMON
>   ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
>   Dread Powers: Agonize ••, Ecstasy •••••

Comment: I've edited your answer to use a quote block instead of a code block. There are symbols in your answer that don't show up in my browser ([it looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/ILwGobr.png)) - do they still show up for you? I suspect there might be character set problems -- are you able to replace them with HTML entities? I find FileFormat.info has [a very handy Unicode symbol directory](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm).

Comment: Neither of those things are about the same kind of 'demon'--the Unchained--described in Mortal Remains at all. Inferno and core Hunter are basically completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

First, all three classes of 'demons' described in Mortal Remains are a completely different kind of being from the demons described in the HtV core book. They have virtually nothing in common.

## Greater Demons

The section on greater demons describes their power over unnatural luck and coincidence in their favor, and points to one particular Dread Power:

> The Dread Power Glitch can model many of these occurrences.

The description for *Glitch* also re emphasizes that it's possessed by demons:

> This Dread
>   Power is a common part of a demon’s repertoire; their ability to
>   toy with reality gets them out of many binds.

Also as described in MR, greater demons have an Apocalyptic Form, which you can represent with the Dread Power *Biomechanical Nightmare*. The Dread Power's description explicitly mentions demons having it:

> Demons commonly have biomechanical forms, as well as do certain fairies.

Still others can be inferred from comparing the Dread Powers to things in the *Demon: the Descent* book. These are the Dread Powers in MR that seem like they were obviously inspired by demons' Embeds, Exploits, and demonic form powers.

- MR's *Cloak of Authority*: DtD's *Authorized*.
- MR's *Degradation*: DtD's *Shatter* or *Disintegrate*.
- MR's *Embolden the Mob*: DtD's *Riot*.
- MR's *Eye For Desire*: DtD's *Heart's Desire*. (*"Some monsters can peer into the soul, and see a victim’s weakness. Many demons can see and subsequently exploit a person’s flaws."*)
- MR's *Flicker and Flash*: DtD's *Teleportation* Propulsion.
- MR's *Reap*: DtD's *Merciless Gunman*.
- MR's *Tempest*: DtD's *Rain of Blood*.
- MR's *Scapegoating*: DtD's *Everybody Hates Him* or *Everybody Knows*.

## Lesser Demons

The lesser demons in MR, on the other hand, may describe multiple different things grouped together. Imps correspond with what were eventually labeled Imperatives in *Demon Storyteller's Guide* (which came out much later than Mortal Remains). Voyeurs could easily be Imperatives too, but more resemble Whisperers from the book *Inferno*. Devourers resemble Strix from *Vampire: the Requiem*, but also appear possibly God-Machine-created or technological, described as physically invading and puppeteering people's bodies with a lattice of circuitry.

For Voyeurs and Imps, the schtick of urging humans to do things could use the Dread Powers *The Oldest Temptation* and *Twist Desires*. Devourers are one-trick body puppeteers with no other powers besides what's in their description (devouring human flesh and blood for Willpower).

## Institutional Demons

Institutional demons aren't even individuals, and don't really use Dread Powers, they have powerful social Merits and human agents instead. They seem to also be known as Infrastructure in *The God-Machine Chronicle*, or arguably as demonic Agencies.